# Почему разные падежи в "выйти на экраны" и "выйти на дисках"?

Tags: падежи, управление

Мы говорим, что фильм [*вышел на экраны*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&all=x). Почему винительный?

Тот же фильм через полгода вышел *на диски* или *на дисках*? А вот программа вышла (издана, выпущена) *на телефоны* или *на телефонах?*

Answer (score 5):

Вероятно, вы исходите из того, что с предолгом "на" употребляется какой-то один падеж, но это не так. В зависимости от контекста,  падеж существительного  с предлогом "на" может быть винительный или предложный, см. например, такую учебную таблицу:
http://www.fio.ru/tables/noun/predlogi-padezhey-suschestvitelnykh/

Поэтому вполне можно

> ... выйти **на** дорог**у** **на** каблук**ах** и упасть навзничь.

Применительно к вашим примерам, такие контекстные различия, конечно же, есть. Нужный падеж выявляется, как обычно, вопросом:

> *вышел **на** экран**ы*** (куда [букв. **на что**] вышел? - на публику,
>   на экраны, которые показывают публике за деньги в кинотеатрах) -
>   винительный падеж
>
> *вышел **на** диска**х*** (в какой форме вышел: **на чем**, на каких носителях
>   продается, распространяется? - **на** диск**ах**, которые можно
>   купить) - предложный падеж

Программа **вышла для** телефонов (если распространяется отдельно от самих телефонов), но может распространяться **установленной на** новые телефон**ы**.

Comment: Понятно, что падежи разные могут быть. Вопрос: почему с появлением экранов начал использоваться вин. п., как "выйти на бульвар", а не пред., как "выйти на бумаге"? А если фильм вышел "на (кино)экраны" (это не идиома), почему бы ему не выйти "на телефоны"? Или "на телефонах", раз уж они, как и диски, носители информации?

Comment: Очень просто: бумага с продукцией размножается и продается, а "экраны с фильмами" - нет. Поэтому разные падежи в таких сочетаниях. И обратите внимание на разницу между значениями "выйти" и "быть выпущенным" (второе с "экраном" не сочетается; правильно **выпущен в прокат**, но не "на экраны" - это звучит просторечно). Так что это _идиома_ (пусть и возникшая в своё время из журналистского штампа): фильм буквально **вышел куда-то** (из мест хранения, производства), а не **на чем-то**.

Comment: Это максимум единство, но никак не идиома, потому что смысл ясен из составных частей.

Answer (score 0):

> Мы говорим, что фильм вышел на экраны. Почему винительный?

Странная постановка вопроса. По грамматике так требуется. Здесь тот же синтаксис, что и в конструкции, к примеру, "вышел в поле" или "приехал в город". То есть "куда?" Если русский у вас — родной, сомневаться в падеже не приходится.

> Тот же фильм через полгода вышел на диски или на дисках?

Еще более странный вопрос. Я не могу представить разумного контекста, когда бы "вышел куда" употреблялось в отношении дисков.

Давайте так. 
У вас падежи во фразах ***"Я приехал на свидание"*** и ***"Я приехал на трамвае"*** сомнений не вызывают? Так вот с фильмом с точки зрения грамматики абсолютно те же конструкции.

> А вот программа вышла (издана, выпущена) на телефоны или на
>   телефонах?

Никак. В крайнем случае — **для телефонов**, да и в этом случае вызывает некоторое ощущение стилистической тяжеловесности. Программа сама по себе не выходит и не выпускается. Если вопрос не умозрителен, то я бы рекомендовал использовать конструкцию наподобие 
***Выпущен релиз 2.0 программы "Русский для чайников" для смартфонов.***

От отчаяния решился написать чуть более подробно то, что (как мне казалось) самоочевидно.

Фильм "на экранах" выйти не может, что бы там не говорил grizzly. Это изначально абсурд, на экранах могут проецироваться изображения, но экран не является носителем информации. Он может выйти на (на чем?) кинопленке или на каком-то другом носителе. На дисках например. Ну, и наоборот, естественно, на диски он выйти не может. Разве что кто-то не додумается использовать диск в качестве кино/теле-экрана.

И по-поводу "значений". У глагола "выйти" можно насчитать миллион значений (не надо никакого Апресяна спрашивать, как grizzly советует), ***но в данных конструкциях ("вышел на экраны" и "вышел на дисках") значение абсолютно одно.*** 
Разница в смысле всего высказывания в целом как раз и определяется разным управлением. Вышел - куда? - на экраны. Вышел - на чем - на дисках. 
Сам глагол абсолютно не меняет своего значения. В обоих случаях речь идет о появлении фильма в некотором общем доступе.

(++)
Фиксирую, что grizzly в конце концов признал форму "вышел на дисках" ошибкой. Разбираться, чья именно это ошибка уж тем более пытаться как-то её объяснять, нет никакого желания. 
DIXI

Comment: К сожалению, ответ бесполезен. "Выпущен релиз 2.0 программы..." - стилистический кошмар.

Comment: *стилистический кошмар кошмар* - два раза?  Так я оба раза и несогласен.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: я не говорил, что фильм может "выйти на экранах" (что бы там не говорил behemothus :)

Comment: @grizzly не поленитесь посмотреть ваши комментарии под вашим же ответом. Вы не только это сказали, вы даже заявили, что искали объяснение этому у меня. А на мое недоумение предложили поискать мне что-то получше.

Comment: @behemothus Я говорил о желании объяснить **распространённую ошибку**. Вы действительно не понимаете, или продолжаете сознательно передёргивать?

Comment: @grizzly *Я говорил о желании объяснить распространённую ошибку.*  - Я правильно понял, что эта ошибка заключалась в использовании формы "выйти на экранах?" Тогда вам, как я полагаю, следует извиниться за свое "уточнение" в комментарии выше и признать, что оно не соответствует истине.  А не обвинять меня в передергивании.

Comment: @grizzly И еще. Я готов поверить в недоразцмение, если собеседник реагирует на мои вопросы сразу. А когда он на прямой вопрос зачем-то посылает меня к Апресяну... Простите, не могу поверить вашим объяснениям.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, теперь я понимаю Ваше видение ситуации. Согласен, что оно оправдывает такое поведение.

Comment: Какое поведение, господь с Вами? Я отнюдь не намерен оправдываться. Я был немного резок в комментарии, который удалил (отнюдь не по причине его резкости), но все остальное никаким образом не предмет для обсуждения моего "поведения".  И вот теперь вынужден разговор закончить.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос сложный и интересный, если копнуть чуть глубже.

Глагол **выйти** имеет широкое и сложное дерево значений. Я думаю, что к данному вопросу относятся в первую очередь группы значений **появиться** (в подгруппе "стать доступным") и **быть обнародованным**. Ситуация осложняется тем, что между этими значениями нет чёткой границы (думаю даже, что в реальном употреблении они пересекаются большей частью).

Помимо устойчивых выражений с однозначным управлением [**вышла в свет (книга)**, **вышла в эфир (передача)**] есть и вариативные: **вышла на страницах журнала (повесть)** (здесь значения "появилась" и "обнародована" совмещаются в каких-то пропорциях) и **вышла на страницы журнала (дискуссия)** (здесь нет значения "появилась", но к значению "обнародована" добавляется значение "выйти откуда-то" [подобное буквальное значение для фильмов Alex_ander упоминает в комментариях к своему ответу]).

Ещё пример: *тема вышла на первые полосы всех газет* (обнародована и вышла в лидеры) и *сенсация вышла на первых полосах всех газет* (появилась, обнародована).

Поскольку семантика глаголов **выйти** (на экраны) и **появиться** (на экранах) в данном контексте очень близка, ошибки в управлении здесь неизбежны. Именно поэтому, я считаю, настолько широко распространено среди носителей языка выражение "выйти на экранах" (пропорции гугло-поиска для выражений "вышли на экраны" и "вышли на экранах" 3:2; с другими словоформами "выйти" пропорции меньше, но всё равно значительны).

Что касается телефонов. Они сегодня распространены настолько повсеместно, что никакими требованиями не удастся их владельцев ограничить свой язык архаичными формами при описании новых явлений в жизни. Поэтому выражения "игра / программа вышла на телефоны / телефонах" будут употребляться всё активнее и со временем попадут в словари. Но правил сейчас нет и носители языка вынуждены использовать своё языковое чутьё. Думаю, что выбор в этих случаях должен определяться контекстом (считает ли говорящий, что игра прежде всего "появилась" или, например, "расширила ареал обитания").

Comment: grizzly, помилуйте, ну при чем значения глагола выйти? Падежи определяет семантика высказывания. "Вышел в магазин" и "Вышел на костылях" - это разные значения "вышел" или как?

Comment: @behemothus Я попытался объяснить, почему так широко распространено выражение "выйти на экранах" среди носителей языка. Я вообще взялся объяснять это только потому, что меня не удовлетворило Ваше решение: если язык родной, то сомневаться не приходится. Вы не согласны с моим объяснением? Предложите что-то лучше. Это всё относится также к вопросу о телефонах.

Comment: А на мой вопрос все-таки ответь-те пожалуйста.  Действительно интересно, где вы тут "увидели разницу в значениях".

Comment: PS минус - это все чем я могу отреагировать на данный момент.

Comment: Я удалил одни комментарий просто потому, что убедился: частотность этого уродца "вышел на экранах" действительно зашкаливает, даже если исключить спорные случаи. Но этот никак не приближает меня к разгадке тайны, что такое "разных значений" и где об этом мог говорит Апресян.

Comment: @behemothus Ничуть не возражаю против минусов (мне вообще жаль, что на форуме сложилась традиция болезненного отношения к ним). И предлагаю на этом поставить точку, чтобы не усугублять недоразумения (я всё равно не понимаю, о каких значениях Вы спрашиваете в контексте моего ответа и теперь, вдобавок, боюсь представить, что Вы надеетесь найти у Апресяна).

Comment: Как скажете, я потому минус и поставил, что понял: внятного ответа ждать бесполезно.